# Using non-standard characters for accent marks

Tags: symbols, unicode, accents

I have a text of poems (psalms) that will be sung or chanted.  To indicate the word where there's a change in the music, an accent is placed above the syllable in that word.  Then the singers know that's where to change notes.  The standard acute/grave accent is too small for this.  It needs to be larger and stand out more.  I want to use the elegant-looking [Bengali Currency Number One](http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/char/09F4-bengali-currency-numerator-one).  I don't know how to get this into LaTeX.  I'm using MikTeX2.9 with TeXMaker.  I already have some [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117864/how-to-increase-size-of-the-diacritic-accent-mark-selectively-without-changing-t) to make any character into an accent.  However, after searching for a way to get this particular character into LaTeX, I haven't found a way to do it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You link to a generic image for the character but to actually get a specific glyph you will need a font that covers that range. classic (pdf)TeX can not use system Unicode fonts so unless you are using xelatex or lualatex this will be more or less hard depending if it is already done by some package. But using a specific font for this rather than just using a larger accent seems to be making thing massively more complicated than need be, you can take the acute accent from any font you use in TeX already and scale it arbitrarily large then position it over the letters.

Comment: Thank you for this reply.  How do I scale an accent?  For example, If I input \'{e}, how do change the size of the accent above the e?

Comment: See also [this question for another approach to the same problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112041).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is easy to get a large accent, eg  `{\Huge\'{}}` positioning it over a normal size letter usually means a bit of trial and error to get something that looks right but perhaps:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\biga[1]{\leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
\halign{##\cr\hss\makebox(0,0){\Huge\'{}}\hss\cr\noalign{\vskip-3pt}#1\cr}}}
\begin{document}



aaaaaaa\biga{a}z\biga{B}zzzzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you (also @Caleb), the above has worked perfectly.  However, now I've changed the font from Linux Libertine to Times and instead of giving me large accents above the letters, LaTeX is simply drawing a box with an "X" around the letter in the pdf output, with no accent.  On the other hand, if I use a command like \'{e}, then it places the accent above the letter at normal size as usual.  This is happening with a lot of fonts I try.  I'm using XeLaTeX.  Any ideas?  Is there a workaround?  Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: @Ryan odd, try replacing `\'{}` by `^^b4` (U+00B4 is SPACING ACUTE)

Comment: David, worked like a charm! Thank you very much!  You can disregard a comment a left on another thread with a similar question.  Appreciate it.